# centering nav text within a grid

Tags: html, css, nav, centering

I am trying to equally place my 8 nav links across my nav bar.

Here is my nav HTML:

```
 <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="destinations.html">Destinations</a></li>
      <li><a href="culture.html">Culture</a></li>
      <li><a href="attractions.html">Attractions</a></li>
      <li><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
      <li><a href="media.html">Media</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

I am using a basic grid and am trying to place each of the 8 links equally into 1/8 of the nav.

My css for the grid :

```
.col-1-8 {
width:12.5% }
```

I am applying this class to each of the 8 li, but can't seem to get them all centered equally.

If someone could help me out here, i'd be very happy!

thanks

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) for this.

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  /* justify-content: space-between; */
  
  background: yellow;
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="destinations.html">Destinations</a></li>
      <li><a href="culture.html">Culture</a></li>
      <li><a href="attractions.html">Attractions</a></li>
      <li><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
      <li><a href="media.html">Media</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: This haven't got the same width all elements

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I don't think that was the intention of OP any way. He wants to distribute the elements nicely.

Comment: Then, you need to read the question again. That question starts with `I am trying to equally place my 8 nav links across my nav bar.`. Note the word **equally**

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Again, that's not necessarily what I think he wants. He actually just wants to center the items, but the best way to do so he thought was by giving all of them the same width. If I'm wrong, then he'll just accept the other answer, biggy.

Comment: I wanted the elements spaced as per this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This code does exactly what you want to obtain, I think that you didn't apply box-sizing border-box or text-align center.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQVQGr

HTML:

```
 <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="destinations.html">Destinations</a></li>
      <li><a href="culture.html">Culture</a></li>
      <li><a href="attractions.html">Attractions</a></li>
      <li><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
      <li><a href="media.html">Media</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav ul {
  background-color:yellow;
  overflow:auto;
  list-style:none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 800px; 
}

nav ul>li {
  float:left;
  width: 12.5%;
  text-align: center

}
```

Comment: `overflow:auto` is a nasty trick to clear the floats, and it will most definitely come and bite you. I advise using `clear:both;display:table;content:"";` on `nav ul:after`.